# How can I do an insert where not exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, not-exists

I'd like to combine an insert query with a "where not exists" so as not to violate PK constraints. However, syntax such as the following gives me an `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'` error -

```
INSERT INTO myTable(columns...)
VALUES(values...)
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT *
    FROM myTable
    WHERE pk_part1 = value1,
        AND pk_part2 = value2)
```

How can I accomplish this?

(In general, can you combine an insert with a where clause?)

Comment: Is it MySQL. I'm not sure if MySQL will support such sub-query.

Comment: @Nishant - No, not MySql, there's a SQL tag... I'll add a SQL Server tag for clarity

Comment: You should use a stored procedure and have a look at following link: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/07/30/60273.aspx

Comment: @Tim: I added the mysql-error tag because this was originally tagged as mysql, and added the error tag based on the "incorrect syntax" error which is consistent with MySQL.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I don't think it was ever tagged as mysql - you can check the original version in the post history

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO myTable(columns...)
Select values...
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT *
    FROM myTable
    WHERE pk_part1 = value1,
        AND pk_part2 = value2)
```

**Edit:**
After reading martins link, If admit, that the best solution is:

```
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO myTable(columns...)
    values( values...)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() <> 2627
      RAISERROR etc
END CATCH;
```

Comment: This can still lead to attempts to insert duplicates under load. If the OP is on SQL Server 2008 using `Merge` avoids this issue.

Comment: As described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407857/only-inserting-a-row-if-its-not-already-there

Comment: @Martin I guess, I have to rewrite more, than this answer

Comment: [EAFP](http://www.acronymfinder.com/EAFP.html) or [JFDI](http://www.acronymfinder.com/JFDI.html)

Comment: The same question for Oracle seems to be answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147874/oracle-insert-if-row-not-exists

Comment: In mysql, It does not work without adding (from tableName ) after first select , INSERT INTO myTable(columns...) Select values... from myTable WHERE NOT EXISTS

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to keep a unique list of values is to either a) set the column(s) as the primary key or b) create a unique constraint on the column(s).  Either of these would result in an error when attempting to insert/update values to something that already exists in the table, when a NOT EXISTS/etc would fail silently -- no error, query will execute properly.

That said, use an INSERT/SELECT (don't include the VALUES portion):

```
INSERT INTO myTable(columns...)
SELECT [statically defined values...]
  FROM ANY_TABLE
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM myTable
                    WHERE pk_part1 = value1
                      AND pk_part2 = value2)
```

Comment: It generates a PK error... I want to avoid that error by checking to make sure it's there first

Comment: @froadie: I understand, but I'd be using the error returned to be able to inform the user that the value(s) already exist.

Comment: If the tuple exist then the following error raised: 

VALUES clause must contain at least one element. Empty elements are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

None of the examples worked for me... so I suggest this example:

```
INSERT INTO database_name.table_name(column_name)
SELECT column_name
  FROM database_name.table_name
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM database_name.table_name
                    WHERE column_name = 'Column Value')
```

Answer (score -1):

mysql has the insert ignore query:

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued. Data conversions that would trigger errors abort the statement if IGNORE is not specified. With IGNORE, invalid values are adjusted to the closest values and inserted; warnings are produced but the statement does not abort. You can determine with the mysql_info() C API function how many rows were actually inserted into the table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is also available