# Does MySQL support "if not exists"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database where i put some societies and their employees. The thing is that two societies can have an employe with the same name (but they are different person). So when I want to insert an employe (stagiaire) I try to check if it exists for this society.
Here is my query :

```
INSERT INTO stagiaire(Nom,Email,Telephone,IDSociete )
VALUES('Paul','ppk@mail.fr','0000000000','7' )
WHERE(SELECT stagiaire.ID FROM stagiaire 
LEFT JOIN societe ON stagiaire.IDSociete = societe.ID
WHERE stagiaire.Nom = 'Paul' AND societe.NomSoc = 'PachaKebab') NOT EXISTS
```

Heres 'Paul' already exists in the society 'Promoplantes' and I have another 'Paul' in the society 'PachaKebab' (ID = 7) the one I try to insert.

I tried few things like `IF NOT EXISTS` the my INSERT query (between begin/end) but it seems like phpMyAdim (SQL Server that i use) can't unserstand the `IF NOT EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` code.

Is that true ? Or do I have an error in my code that I dont see ?

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is a name clash?

Comment: FYI phpmyadmin is a  database administration tool, your database engine is probably MySQL,

Comment: where NOT EXISTS (select....)

Comment: Maybe this question can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707063/how-can-i-do-an-insert-where-not-exists

Comment: read the doc. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: Don't use `not exists` when a simple unique index will do the job.

Comment: I already read the doc. @Phylog

Comment: @Phylogenesis what do you mean ?

Comment: I've never used the world's favourite MySQL client (I prefer desktop clients) so I hope I'm not spreading wrong information but I'm pretty sure that it doesn't use its own SQL syntax. Who would want to learn yet another SQL dialect that's only valid for a single client?

Comment: If you add a unique index to the composite field `(Nom, IDSociete)` then the DB itself will prevent you from entering a name collision and you don't need to use an `if not exists` clause on every attempt to insert.

Comment: @Phylogenesis That doesn't help when inserting multiple rows in one batch, as the violation of the unique key will abort the entire batch, rather than allowing in those rows which don't conflict. You could do it with an `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, if MySQL supports that, though that's no longer very simple for someone new to SQL. (The query in the original question may only have one row, but tips that don't generalise to similar problems should be given with care.)

Comment: @IMSoP If you're inserting many records in a single batch, then the equivalent `if not exists` clause becomes even more ridiculous. Nevertheless, every best-practice is to put restrictions like this into indexes and constraints, so the one time you forget to add logical clauses into your SQL statements does not lead to broken/orphaned data.

Comment: @Phylogenesis The best practise I've always been exposed to is to have the constraints, but never deliberately rely on them - the application should be avoiding creating duplicate data so that it can handle it more gracefully, rather than having to roll back a transaction when some constraint fires an error. I agree that "not exists" is not the most scalable solution here, but "just use unique constraint and catch the errors" isn't particularly either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE NOT EXISTS

```
INSERT INTO stagiaire(Nom,Email,Telephone,IDSociete )
SELECT 'Paul','ppk@mail.fr','0000000000','7'
FROM stagiaire
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT stagiaire.ID FROM stagiaire 
LEFT JOIN societe ON stagiaire.IDSociete = societe.ID
WHERE stagiaire.Nom = 'Paul' AND societe.NomSoc = 'PachaKebab')
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @TheTinyCat Can you post what error message you got?

Comment: @TheTinyCat So, try adding a LIMIT 1 at the end of the query

Comment: Okay its works pretty good even if i dont understand how the query works x). Thanks body

Answer (score 0):

Use not exists and restructuring your query

```
   INSERT INTO stagiaire(Nom,Email,Telephone,IDSociete )
    Select Nom,Email,Telephone,IDSociete
    From stagiaire s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from societe x
    WHERE x.id = s.IDSociete)
And s.IDSociete = 7
```

Comment: I dont understand your 'SELECT 1 (?) FROM...'

Comment: using not exists or exist will only need at least a match, no need to read all the data

Comment: Yes but '1' means nothing. Or is it a binary (or boolean) condition ?

Comment: select 1 is just a confirmation that there is a record other will return blank... it's not a boolean or bit. just how we test if there is a match

Comment: Okay so it works like a boolean conditions. But its not i get it. thanks.