# INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...) WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)

Tags: oracle10g, insert-into

I have the following query to insert a record if it does not already exists:

```
INSERT INTO "BMAN_TP1"."CELLS_TEXT" ("SET_ID", "CELL_ID")
VALUES (291565, 4256)

WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT "SET_ID", "CELL_ID"
    FROM "BMAN_TP1"."CELLS_TEXT"
    WHERE ("SET_ID"=291565)
    AND ("CELL_ID"=4256)
)
```

I know it can't work, because you can't use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause with `INSERT INTO VALUES`, but only with `INSERT INTO SELECT (...)`.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

**PLEASE NOTE:**
I can't use Oracle's `SELECT 291565, 4256 FROM DUAL` because *it should also work with SQL Server*.

I can't use `MERGE` for the same reason.

Comment: This StackOverflow thread has the answer - use the MERGE function [Oracle insert if not exists statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824764/oracle-insert-if-not-exists-statement)

Comment: possible duplicate of [oracle insert if row not exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147874/oracle-insert-if-row-not-exists)

Comment: As I said, Oracle custom statements cannot be a solution for me.

Comment: `MERGE` also exists on MS SQL Server since version 2008, see [this MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: Ok, didn't know about that. Let's say i do not want to use `MERGE`, still looking for something more general.