# Fastest way to check if row exist

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Before a `select SOMETHING into v_something`, I would like to know if my query returns a row.

Here are a good methods, but it cost two `select` if the row exists :

```
select count(1) into isRowExists from PERSON where CONDITION='Something';

if (isRowExists > 0) then
    select NAME into v_name from PERSON where CONDITION='Something';
else
    raise name_not_found;
end if;

select count(1) into isRowExists from CAR where CONDITION='Something';

if (isRowExists > 0) then
    select MODEL into v_model from CAR where CONDITION='Something';
else
    raise model_not_found;
end if;
```

Or something like that :

```
select NAME into v_name from PERSON where CONDITION='Something';

select MODEL into v_model from CAR where CONDITION='Something';

exception
    when no_data_found then
        --do_something
```

But with this method, I don't know if the problem came from `PERSON` or `CAR`...

Is there any other solution ? Like sending a parameter to an `exception` ?

Comment: Use when no_data_found with 2 separate exception blocks

Comment: @6ton Do you have an example ?

Comment: Why do you want to check row existence before retrieving the value from the row? By definition, if your query fails to return a row, then the row doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        select NAME into v_name from PERSON where CONDITION='Something';
    exception
        when no_data_found then
        --do_something
    END;

    BEGIN
        select MODEL into v_model from CAR where CONDITION='Something';
    exception
        when no_data_found then
            --do_something
    END;
END;
/
```

Comment: But this requires repeatable read, so you will need to run at [serializable isolation level](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10743/consist.htm#330099)

Answer (score 3):

For the second method, you can just wrap each in a `begin`/`end` block:

```
begin
    select NAME into v_name from PERSON where CONDITION='Something';
exception
    when no_data_found then
        --do_something
end;

begin
    select MODEL into v_model from CAR where CONDITION='Something';

exception
    when no_data_found then
        --do_something
end;
```

Comment: If you add `and ROWNUM = 1` then this solution will also work if there is more that one row that meets the `WHERE` criteria.

Answer (score 1):

if name is not null you can try this:

```
select (select NAME from PERSON where CONDITION='Something') into v_name 
from dual;

if v_name is null then 
...
```

I wouldn't say that catching NO_DATA_FOUND is the fastest way. It really depends. Sometimes it's better to perform count and then fetch. COUNT works faster then retrieving data so if there is a high probability that a row doesn't exist COUNT will be more beneficial. And Oracle uses some caching mechanisms so the second query with the same WHERE will be performed faster.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution to avoid exceptions:

```
declare
  client_name varchar2(100);
  model_name varchar2(100);

  cursor clients (p_id number) is
    select client_name from client_table where client_id = p_id;

  cursor models (p_id number) is
    select model_name from model_table where model_id = p_id;

begin
  -- variant 1
  for i in clients(123) loop
    client_name := i.client_name;
    exit;
  end loop;

  -- variant 2
  open models(456);
  fetch models into model_name;

  -- if you need to process "no data found" situation: 
  if models%notfound then
     <do something>
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

#### MERGE

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147874/oracle-insert-if-row-not-exists) gives an example for Oracle.

---

#### INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS

I'm not certain this would work in Oracle, I believe it works for general SQL RDBMS like MySQL and PostgreSQL.

```
INSERT INTO v_name(name) 
   SELECT name FROM person 
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM person WHERE <name/condition> = <value>
   ); 

-- UPDATE ...; -- Add UPDATE statement here to complete an UPSERT query
```

---

Please express reason for downvotes :)

Answer (score -2):

You can parametrized the query and that will cost you 1 select query at time like

```
@tablename varchar,
@conditionparameter varchar,

select count(1) into isRowExists from tablename where CONDITION='+conditionparameter+' ;
if(@tablename ='PERSON ' and isRowExists > 0)

select NAME into v_name from PERSON where CONDITION='Something';

elseif (@tablename ='CAR' and isRowExists > 0)

select MODEL into v_model from CAR where CONDITION='Something';

else
raise name_not_found;
end if;
```

This is generalized idea you can further optimized the above mentioned query.

Comment: This is a SQL Server answer. The tags on the question clearly specify that it's an Oracle question.